# Codeigniter uploading website failed to open a stream

Tags: codeigniter, include-path

I have error when I upload my personal website. This is the error that I get:

> Warning:
>   include(/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/thefourpobu/public_html/tep/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Comment: the error clearly shows that, you've deleted `errors` folder from your view. Just add that folder again. and it'll start to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

This got me too.  From the CodeIgniter upgrade doc:

Step 8: Replace your error templates

In CodeIgniter 3.0, the error templates are now considered as views and have been moved to the application/views/errors directory.

Furthermore, we’ve added support for CLI error templates in plain-text format that unlike HTML, is suitable for the command line. This of course requires another level of separation.

### It is safe to move your old templates from application/errors to application/views/errors/html, but you’ll have to copy the new application/views/errors/cli directory from the CodeIgniter archive.

You just need to copy over the errors folder provided in ver 3.0 to your views folder.